# Compile a part of an environment and collect the body

Tags: environments, compiling, collect, body

There are a question and a answer in an environment.
I typeset the question. Then typeset the question and the answer.
How can I do this. My file has over 100 questions.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newcounter{exc}
\newenvironment{ex}{\refstepcounter{exc}\par\noindent\textbf{Ex \theexc.}}{\ignorespacesafterend}
\newcommand{\loigiai}[1]{}
\begin{document}
  \begin{ex}
  Content of the question 1
  \loigiai{Answer of the question 1}
  \end{ex}
  \begin{ex}
    Content of the question 1
    \loigiai{Answer of the question 1}
   \end{ex}
%\showanswer collect the environment's bodies and inpunt as below
\begin{center}
\textbf{Answer}
\end{center}
\setcounter{exc}{0}
\renewcommand{\loigiai}[1]{\par \textit{Answer} #1}
  \begin{ex}
  Content of the question 1
  \loigiai{Answer of the question 1}
  \end{ex}
  \begin{ex}
    Content of the question 1
    \loigiai{Answer of the question 1}
   \end{ex}
\end{document}
```

#update 6/8/2021

The problem is almost solvent by helping of the tokcycle package. When ex has an option, there is a error about illegal Illegal parameter number in definition.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{exc}
\newenvironment{ex}[1][]{\refstepcounter{exc}\par\noindent\textbf{Ex \theexc.} }{\ignorespacesafterend}
\newcommand{\loigiainul}[1]{}
\newcommand{\eloigiai}{}
\newcommand{\loigiaifull}[1]{\gdef\eloigiai{\par \textit{Answer} #1}}
\xtokcycleenvironment\Tracnghiem
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\processtoks{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\let\loigiai\loigiainul}
  {\tcafterenv{%
    \begin{center}\textbf{Answer}\end{center}
    \setcounter{exc}{0}
    \let\loigiai\loigiaifull
\renewenvironment{ex}[1][]{\refstepcounter{exc}\par\noindent
    \begin{tcolorbox}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{\textbf{Ex \theexc.}}
    {\textbf{Ex \theexc (\textit{#1}).}}
}
{\end{tcolorbox}\ignorespacesafterend\eloigiai}    
    \the\cytoks}%
  }
\begin{document}
\Tracnghiem
  \begin{ex}
  Content of the question 1
  \loigiai{Answer of the question 1}
  \end{ex}
  \begin{ex}
    Content of the question 2
    \loigiai{Answer of the question 2}
   \end{ex}
\endTracnghiem
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I use an extended token cycle to both gather the `\Exercise` pseudo-environment tokens (into the token list `\cytoks`) and to set up both recitations with the proper output.

In point of fact, the tokens are cycled through once and gathered.  They are then output twice, the second time with a revised definition for `\loigiai`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newcounter{exc}
\newenvironment{ex}{\refstepcounter{exc}\par\noindent\textbf{Ex \theexc.}}{\ignorespacesafterend}
\newcommand{\loigiainul}[1]{}
\newcommand{\loigiaifull}[1]{\par \textit{Answer} #1}
\xtokcycleenvironment\Exercises
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\processtoks{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\let\loigiai\loigiainul}
  {\tcafterenv{%
    \begin{center}\textbf{Answer}\end{center}
    \setcounter{exc}{0}
    \let\loigiai\loigiaifull
    \the\cytoks}%
  }
\begin{document}
\Exercises
  \begin{ex}
  Content of the question 1
  \loigiai{Answer of the question 1}
  \end{ex}
  \begin{ex}
    Content of the question 2
    \loigiai{Answer of the question 2}
   \end{ex}
\endExercises
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**ADDENDUM**

Answer to EDITED question

In the EDITED question, the use of `#1` in the tokcycle `\Tracnghiem` environment is not correct, because the OP wants the `#1` to refer to the argument of the `ex` environment.  Making it `##1` pushes it into the argument of `\@aftertokcycle`...still not good enough.  `####1` makes it the argument of `\tcendgroup`.  Finally `########1` makes it the argument of `ex`, as desired.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{exc}
\newenvironment{ex}[1][]{\refstepcounter{exc}\par\noindent\textbf{Ex \theexc.} }{\ignorespacesafterend}
\newcommand{\loigiainul}[1]{}
\newcommand{\eloigiai}{}
\newcommand{\loigiaifull}[1]{\gdef\eloigiai{\par \textit{Answer} #1}}
\xtokcycleenvironment\Tracnghiem
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\processtoks{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\let\loigiai\loigiainul}
  {\tcafterenv{%
    \begin{center}\textbf{Answer}\end{center}
    \setcounter{exc}{0}
    \let\loigiai\loigiaifull
\renewenvironment{ex}[1][]{\refstepcounter{exc}\par\noindent
    \begin{tcolorbox}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{########1}{}}{\textbf{Ex \theexc.}}
    {\textbf{Ex \theexc (\textit{########1}).}}
}
{\end{tcolorbox}\ignorespacesafterend\eloigiai}    
    \the\cytoks}%
  }
\begin{document}
\Tracnghiem
  \begin{ex}[Hi Mom]%
  Content of the question 1
  \loigiai{Answer of the question 1}
  \end{ex}
  \begin{ex}
    Content of the question 2
    \loigiai{Answer of the question 2}
   \end{ex}
\endTracnghiem
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I may not fully understand the OP's use cases, but there may be no need to redefine `ex` in the tokcycle environment.  In that case, one can avoid all the `####...` mumbo-jumbo and maybe this would suffice:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{exc}
\newcommand{\loigiainul}[1]{}
\newcommand{\eloigiai}{}
\newcommand{\loigiaifull}[1]{\gdef\eloigiai{\par \textit{Answer} #1}}
\xtokcycleenvironment\Tracnghiem
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\processtoks{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
  {\let\loigiai\loigiainul}
  {\tcafterenv{%
    \begin{center}\textbf{Answer}\end{center}
    \setcounter{exc}{0}
    \let\loigiai\loigiaifull
    \the\cytoks}%
  }
\newenvironment{ex}[1][]{\refstepcounter{exc}\par\noindent
    \begin{tcolorbox}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{\textbf{Ex \theexc.}}
    {\textbf{Ex \theexc (\textit{#1}).}}
}
{\end{tcolorbox}\ignorespacesafterend\eloigiai}    

\begin{document}
\Tracnghiem
  \begin{ex}[Hi Mom]%
  Content of the question 1
  \loigiai{Answer of the question 1}
  \end{ex}
  \begin{ex}
    Content of the question 2
    \loigiai{Answer of the question 2}
   \end{ex}
\endTracnghiem
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you the author of tokcycle package. It is very good. Sometimes, i only in put some Excersises. Can It be maked by your package?

Comment: @NamTranLe Yes, I am the author of `tokcycle`.  I'm not exactly sure of your comment's question, but I tried to answer the question above.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: When ex has an option, there is a error about illegal Illegal parameter number in definition. Please help me!

Comment: @NamTranLe Perhaps that is a new question...It sounds perhaps as if the error has nothing to do with the answer provided here, but with the way you have introduced a parameter into the environment.  Without seeing actual code, there really isn't much useful I can say about it.

Comment: I have updated my question (6/8/2021). There is my MWE.

Comment: @NamTranLe See addendum to my answer

Comment: Thank you very much! I have tried to four # symbols. It must be eight # symbols.

Comment: @NamTranLe I edited again to question whether `ex` really needs to be part of the tokcycle definition.  You may be able to avoid this difficulty altogether.

Comment: Thank you very much!